# Complex ArrayList with different type elements

Tags: java, arraylist, complex-data-types

I'm creating a complex data type.
It's an ArrayList (chapters) of ArrayLists (chapter).
However, there are two versions of the chapter, each with it's respected elements and data types.

How could I declare my complex data type so I could add one or another (to have, e.g., ArrayList(chapters) which contains (chapter_typeI,chapter_typeII,chapter_typeII,chapter_typeI,chapter_typeII, etc...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make an abstract class, from which the both type of chapters inherit, and then declare a list of this type.

```
public abstract class AbstractChapter {}

public class ChapterTypeOne extends AbstractChapter {}

public classs ChapterTypeTwo extends AbstractChapter {}

List<AbstractChapter> chapters = new ArrayList<AbstractChapter>;
```

The operations that you are going to call should be declared in the abstract class, and then overriden as necessary in the specific implementations.

Comment: What if I create an object which contains both chapters and use it as an element, but to make sure that one of the chapter always equals null? Every time I generate a chapter, I fill the desired chapter type with desired data and set the other one to null.

I'm not sure if that is good memory-vise, but it would simplyfy the whole deal.

?

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea. Every time a client wants to use the object, it'd have to check which element is not null. It's better OO design to use polymorphism (having one base type, extending functionality with the concrete implementations), so that your clients can directly use the abstract class and not care about the concrete implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to create List of types than actual object if you have clear hierarchy defined.

```
 List<Type> list = new ArrayList<Type>();
```

Now Type can be your interface

```
interface Type {
    void method();
}
```

Now you can have

```
SubType1 implements Type {
    void method() {
        // do something.
    }
}

SubType2 implements Type {
    void method() {
        // do something.
    }
}
```

Also you can use Abstract Skeletal pattern in which you can have class AbstractType with default implementation if required

Comment: if you declare a list as List<? extends Type>, then you cannot add anything to it other than list.add(null), otherwise compile will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use inheritance to define an abstract class "Chapter", and derive the types of chapters from the abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an abstract base class "Chapter", from which ChapterI and ChapterII gets inherited.